# What is the concentration of measure for Gaussian random variables which are independent, but are transformed?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, gaussian, measure-concentration

This might be a too easy question for Mathoverflow, but Googling led to similar questions and answers here (though not the one I was looking for).

The question is split into two:

1. I have a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ such that each $X_{ij}$ is a Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $1$. We have $m > n$. All Gaussians are independent.

I also have a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $||v||_2 \le \epsilon$.

What can we say about the concentration of $Xv$ around the 0 vector?

$E[Xv] = 0$ and the variance should be rather small because $||v||_2 \le \epsilon$.

But what do I do in the general case? Can I have a statement of the following form:

$$p(||Xv||_2 \ge \delta) \le f(\delta,\epsilon,m,n)$$ for some function $f$?

I would rather not use an application of Cauchy-Schwarz, relying on the fact that $||Xv|| \le ||X||||v||_2$ (though if that's the only way, I would like to see that).

2. Same matrix $X$. $E[X^{\top} X] = n I$ (though its rank is going to be smaller than $m$, because $n < m$). Is there a statement such as

$$p(|| X^{\top} X - n I || \ge \delta) \le g(\delta,m,n)?$$

(concentration of $X^{\top}X$ around $I$.) For now, it doesn't matter which matrix norm it would be with.

Comment: For Q1, the law of $Xv$ does not depend on which $v$ you chose, only on the norm of $v$. You might as well choose $v=\epsilon^{1/2}(1,0,0,...)$. Then $\|Xv\|_2^2$ is a $\chi^2$ random variable.

Comment: For Q2, you are asking about the top and bottom eigenvalues of $X^TX$. There is plenty of literature on that - just google wishart matrix norm and minimal singular value of wishart matrix. Gaussian concentration plays an important role here. Precise bounds depend on the relation between $m$ and $n$.